# How to select spark library with our --jars?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, connector, spark-submit

There are multiple version mysql connector library.

```
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
/usr/share/java/mariadb-connector-java.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar


I added external jar library blow path. (spark-default.xml) 
- spark.driver.extraClassPath : ~~~:/usr/share/java/*
- spark.executor.extraClassPath : ~~~:/usr/share/java/*
```

If I run spark-submit command without --jars {specific mysql connector}, what is mysql connector version ? Where can i find? (spark history server?)

ex)

```
jdbc = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
                .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")\
                .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://url:3306/db")\
                .option("user", "XXX")\
                .option("password", "XXX")\
                .option("dbtable", "table")\
                .load()
jdbc.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [environment tab](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/web-ui.html#environment-tab) of the [Spark Web UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/web-ui.html#web-ui) contains a section "Classpath entries". Here you can find all jars that have been added to the classpath of the currently running Spark application and so identify the jar (and the version) of the mysql connector.

[image]

If a history server is running, it's Web UI also contains the same information after the Spark job has finished.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I wonder when I check it there are 4 mysql connectors.
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar

Comment: @hhr The classpath is scanned from front to end. This means the first version of a class that is found in the classpath is used. In your case this means that version 8.0.16 is used. However you should try to avoid this kind of setup where multiple versions of a jar are part of the classpath. I would suggest that you edit your spark-default.xml so that only one specific version is added to the classpath.